# Why does Apache Drill select column with the same name of a different table

Tags: apache-drill

I have a PostgreSQL database linked to a Drill instance.

Whenever I am trying to join 2 tables which both have a column `name` and whenever I want to select this `name` Drill selects the wrong `name` column. What am I doing wrong?

Given the following 2 tables:

```
Department
| id | name |
|----|------|
| 1  |  A   |
| 2  |  B   |

Employee
| id | name | dept | salary |
|----|------|------|--------|
| 1  |  U   |  1   |  100   |
| 2  |  V   |  1   |   75   |
| 3  |  W   |  1   |  120   |
| 4  |  X   |  2   |   95   |
| 5  |  Y   |  2   |  140   |
| 6  |  Z   |  2   |   55   |
```

---

Running

```
select employee.name, employee.salary
from employee
inner join department on employee.dept = department.id
where department.name = 'A'
```

returns

```
| name | salary |
|------|--------|
|  A   |  100   |
|  A   |  75    |
|  A   |  120   |
```

---

Running

```
select dept.name, employee.salary
from employee
inner join department on employee.dept = department.id
where department.name = 'A'
```

returns

```
| name | salary |
|------|--------|
| null |  100   |
| null |  75    |
| null |  120   |
```

---

What does work, but seems very silly to me, is:

```
select dept.name, employee.salary
from employee
inner join (select id, name as deptname from department) as department on employee.dept = department.id
where department.deptname = 'A'
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be because you use

`select dept.name, [...]`

But you have never assigned an alias for the table `department` (`department AS dept`). Hence

`select department.name, [...]`

should yield the value you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I did alias it, though differently: `department) as department`. Apparently there is a bug in Drill which causes this: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/DRILL-5713

Comment: I meant the first query which yields *null* in the column `name`. Thanks for the heads up on the bug, though.